# Non-specific Error in Android studio 3.0 Beta 2

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I can't continue building my app, because I updated Android studio to 3.0 beta 2 and I got this error message:

```
Error:C:\Users\Luk?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.1.aar\f61ab9a130e23c5f88348e1bd6936dcf\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png file not found

Error:C:\Users\Luk?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.1.aar\f61ab9a130e23c5f88348e1bd6936dcf\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png file not found

Error:C:\Users\Luk?\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.0.1.aar\62d1a0a0753b75c4dfbf8fbe3e7715ba\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png file not found
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
>     aapt2 compile --legacy -o C:\AndroidApp\app_name\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug C:\Users\my_name.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.1.aar\f61ab9a130e23c5f88348e1bd6936dcf\res\layout\tooltip.xml
>     Issues:
>      - ERROR: C:\Users\my_name.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.1.aar\f61ab9a130e23c5f88348e1bd6936dcf\res\layout\tooltip.xml file not found

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the `AAPT2` by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to your `gradle.properties` file.

If you want to build the project with aapt2 enabled the follow the below link for changes in project and to get to how fix the error.

Reference : [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

I was using Android studio 3.0.1 In which I disabled the `AAPT2` and it resolved my error.